# Bash alias containing a variable of the current directory

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, sh

I would like to have an alias that uses the current directory as a parameter/variable.

Example: I am currently in

```
/home/me/myproject
```

I want to type "sds" which should execute this:

```
./manage.py --settings=myproject.settings.dev
```

However "myproject" should be different for different folders. So if I'm in

```
/home/me/myotherproject
```

the alias should execute:

```
./manage.py --settings=myotherproject.settings.dev
```

And so on.

I already found out that

```
echo "${PWD##*/}"
```

gets my current directory, but i cannot concatenate it with my entire command.

Thank you so much in advance for any help or pointers!!

Comment: Write a function, not an alias. Aliases should be used just for simple text replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to use single quotes when defining the alias to prevent bash from expanding ${PWD} at definition time:

```
alias ooo='./manage.py --settings="${PWD##*/}.settings.dev"'
```

Comment: Oh my god. So simple and beautiful. I was expecting something "messier". This is perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: A function is simpler: `sds () { ./manage.py --settings="${PWD##*/}.settings.dev"; }`, and isn't subject to as many quoting difficulties.

Comment: @chepner Yep, With a bare minimum of complication, a function works better and is easier to maintain than an alias.